# Retrieve data from database on the home page

Tags: mysql, database, cakephp, frameworks

I am beginner in programming with the CakePhp framework and I want to dispaly data from the database on the HOME page of the website.

I've already create the model + view + controller.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you want this url (model-view-controller) to be your homepage?

Comment: No, i just wanna display data in my home page.
ex : i've PRODUCT table and i wanna display the content in my home page.
when I do this : localhost/x_project/product I can seethe data, but i wanna see the data when i write : localhost/x_project

Many thanx.

Comment: No, sorry not exactly.
I wanna just display data in my home page (the index). That's all.

Comment: You can do that through ajax or in your home controller. Please post your controller code and a snipper of your view

Comment: Thank you for your help.
First of all I wanna say that I am using Cakestrap [https://github.com/Rhym/cakeStrap]

Controller:
 `public function index(){
  $this->helpers = array('Html'); 
  $villes = $this->Ville->find('all');
        $this->set('villes', $villes);
 }`

Part of View:
           
<?php foreach ($ville as $s => $name):
echo $name['name'];
endforeach ?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either do that in your homepage controller

```
<?php
    class HompageController extends AppController {


    public function index(){
      ...

      //For us to be able to call a different Model if it doesnt have a relationship with this model. Instantiate Product Model
      $Products = ClassRegistry::init('Product');

      //to get the data in product database. you can do it in two ways
      //1. use the find method to get all data in Product database
      $myproducts = $Products->find('all');

      //2. or call some function in your Product model e.g. get_products() that return the data.
      $myproducts = $Products->get_products();


      //pass myproducts variable to homepage index
      $this->set('myproducts', $myproducts);


    }
?>
```